# how do you compare a private earthquake insurance company to using CEA in California

Tags: insurance

Regarding getting earthquake insurance in California, how can I compare a private earthquake insurance company (like geovera) to using CEA (California Earthquake Authority) in California. I have Geovera, but I wonder if I should switch.